# How to convert - DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK „ using SED command

Tags: unix, sed

I am getting a special character - '„' in our source files.
we are using the following sed command to replace the '„' character to '&' using the below command line but the operation isn't successful.

cat File.txt | sed 's/\x2\xE1/&/g' > File_New.txt

HEX CODE for „ is #x201E;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think `perl` is far superior than `sed` at working with Unicode text (Assuming here that your file is encoded using UTF-8):

```sh
$ cat input.txt
foo „ bar
$ perl -CSD -pe 's/\N{U+201E}/&/g' input.txt
foo & bar
```

(`-CSD` tells `perl` that standard input/output/error and all opened files are using UTF-8)

But (with the appropriate locale) you can use `sed` and a shell like `bash` that implements [*ANSI-C quoting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to generate the character:

```sh
$ sed 's/'$'\u201E''/\&/g' input.txt
foo & bar
```

or just including the codepoint's UTF-8 bytes directly instead of using an escape sequence will typically work too:

```sh
$ sed 's/„/\&/g' input.txt
foo & bar
```

Some versions of `sed`, like the GNU one, support `\xHH` to represent a byte with the given hexadecimal value, but the Unicode codepoint U+201E is not encoded with those bytes in UTF-8; instead it's the three byte sequence `E2 80 9E`

```sh
$ sed 's/\xE2\x80\x9E/\&/g' input.txt
foo & bar
```

---

All the `sed` examples escape the `&` in the replacement because without the backslash before it, `&` is replaced by the matched text, leaving you right back where you started from.

Answer (score 0):

With a recent GNU `sed`:

```
$ printf '\u201E\n' | hd

00000000  e2 80 9e 0a                                       |....|
00000004

$ printf 'a\u201Eb\n' | LC_ALL=C sed 's/\xe2\x80\x9e/\&/g'
a&b
```

Documentation: `info sed -n 'Locale Considerations'`

Since `&` is a meta character in the replacement section of `sed`'s `s` command it must be escaped.